# How to convert VARCHAR date to a standard MYSQL date format when doing LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, varchar

In my table I have an entire column that has `varchar` date, here is what it looks like: `2/1/2020 02:30:00` (date is m/d/yyyy) I want it to convert to standard MySQL date format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) or maybe if possible a customized date format version . I also wanted to remove the time (02:30:00) if possible. Is there any command that I can run on terminal to convert the entire column or an in import to database, from .xls to .sql file format. Another thing in case it is not possible in MySQL, maybe there is a way in PHP to convert or manipulate the said data. Thank You.

Additional, maybe there is a way to convert the time too, to the standard MySQL time format.

I am not sure how else to change my question, here are some of additional data.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

that is the result of the show warnings, Im not sure were is this going, and what I am doing wrong, but in the given example it is working fine. I will just keep on trying, but I am satisfied that I get two very good suggestion and approach, one on mysql side at php side. Thank you.

Comment: [Can you edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60518572/edit) and include a screenshot of how your date data look like? Also, include the result you've tested with Nick's suggestion.

Comment: try run this query if it return `NULL` or not : `SELECT str_to_date(your_column, '%m/%d/%Y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this translation directly in MySQL, using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to translate the string into a `DATETIME` value, and then [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) to extract the date and time parts:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2/1/2020 02:30:00', '%c/%e/%Y')) AS date,
       TIME(STR_TO_DATE('2/1/2020 02:30:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')) AS time
```

Output:

```
date        time
2020-02-01  02:30:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=517ce21b13d10db235b0705dbb97d647)

Comment: I am not sure how would I do this in the entire column.

Comment: @aaa28 where I have put `'2/1/2020 02:30:00'` just replace that with the column name

Comment: the output is both null. I am not sure what happen.

Comment: @aaa28 I've updated my demo to show reading from a column with values like the ones you've shown in your edit: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=10fd2b2f6a39a11656b1b335a5232d07

Comment: @aaa28 I notice when you ran the query there are some warnings; can you do a `SHOW WARNINGS` after running the query again to show what they are?

Comment: I am importing this (2/1/2020 02:30:00) using a csv file and there are other columns on the csv file. I like what you did in your example. Let say in a csv file I have three columns, name, surname, and birth date. In birthdate column the date is in (2/1/2020 02:30:00). Now on the db, there is a table does have a four columns, which is name, surname, birthdate, and time_of_birth. What I want is to import the csv file, and at the same time split and insert birthdate(csv) into the two columns birthdate and time_of_birth(database table). Thank you.

Comment: I found this tutorial, https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/ there is a section Transforming data while importing, but I do not quite follow how to.

Comment: @aaa28 you would do something like `LOAD DATA INFILE ... (name, surname, @birthdate) SET birthdate = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(@birthdate, '%c/%e/%Y')), time_of_birth = TIME(STR_TO_DATE(@birthdate, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s'))`

Comment: I apologize I cannot update yet, I am running in some trouble regarding secure-file-priv, I cannot upload the .csv yet

Comment: @aaa28 google your problem - there are lots of answers on stackoverflow regarding that issue

Comment: I can now definitely say that your answer solve my problem and it work as intended. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` and `date` function for manipulating this date to MySQL Date Format:

```
$db_date = "2/1/2020  02:30:00";
$new_date = date( "Y-m-d" , strtotime($db_date) );
```

Explanation :

`strtotime($db_date)` this will convert string date to unix timestamp

`date( "Y-m-d" , .... )` this will convert unix timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD (`Y-m-d`) format

Demo : https://3v4l.org/GOr34

Comment: I tried this, this is the data (2/1/2020 06:00:00) and the output is (01/01/1970). It was retrieved from mysql database to be displayed by php in an input with date type.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
    (col1, col2, @str)
    SET col3 = STR_TO_DATE(@str, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

That is, store the incoming string into an @-variable, then convert it within the `LOAD DATA` statement.